# How do you reduce the drag experienced when jumping in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a player character in Unity and jumping works like it should.

But when she starts to fall back down to the ground, I want her to fall quickly.

She is almost floating back down, which interrupts the level's feel.

What parameter am I missing that allows her to fall back to the ground?

I'm going for a Mario feel, where he crests at the jump and then falls fairly quickly back down to the ground.

Comment: Valerie, without any reference to your code, any answer here will be guesswork.

Comment: Please read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, then to allow others to help you, you'll also need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample of your code or whatever you have tried so far to solve the problem.

Comment: If you are using a rigidbody on that character, you could try reducing the  drag. I would also suggest increasing unity's default gravity because it feels really floaty by default.

Comment: I've added some paragraph breaks to make your question a bit more easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add more gravity to whatever component that controls your characters' physics e.g. If you are using a rigidbody component then increase the gravity property.